# Jquery back button not working when animation is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, tizen

I've tried putting background image to my page and i have tried using css class but its not working. the only way its working is through style tag.
But when i use it with animation back is not working.
here is my code snippet.

```
<div data-role="page" id="three" style="background:url('background1.jpg') repeat-x; -webkit-animation: animateBackground 15s infinite;">
        <div  id="1"><img  src="cake.png" alt="where is my cake?" /></div>
        <div  id="2"><img  src="cake.png" alt="where is my cake?" /></div>
        <div  id="3"><img  src="cake.png" alt="where is my cake?" /></div>
       <button id="startShuffle">click</button>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animateBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
```

Please tell me way of doing this or any other way of changing the background image of jquery page.

Comment: can you please post a JSFiddle ?

Comment: dude post the whole code. i cannot come to a decision

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with anything here? There is no JQuery or even any javascript shown in your code. Please provide proper ( and detailed) problem description and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle, works for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/43ny6zna/

I changed the above code from my prior answer to:

```
 parent.history.back();  --> window.history.back();
```

Background appears to animate and back button works.

perhaps the background wasn't working because the actual image location doesn't match. Perhaps it's in a different folder than the html file.

So I replaced it with a link and the code ran fine for loading the background.

Lastly,

Do you have the jQuery library loaded into your page? add this: `<script src=code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js></script>` to your HTML file.